# Error while running Application using PowerApps in microsoft azure

Tags: azure, powerapps, text-analytics-api

I'm trying to run an application on powerapps using Microsoft azure cognitive services. This is a sentimental analysis application where in it gives a sentimental analysis score between 0 to 1 where 1 being positive and 0 being negative based on the sentence we enter. But how much I try and execute I'm not able to handle this error:

TextAnalytics.DetectLanguage failed:

```
{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Invalid request",
  "innerError": {
    "code": "InvalidRequestQueryString",
    "message": "Request contains a query string. Request content should be placed in the request body, not in the url as a query string."
  }
}
```

If anybody has any idea regarding this error and knows how to handle it. Please do help me out to execute this code.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it sounds like your request is malformed. The service is looking for a POST request to be in the format below, sounds like you're sending a parameterized URL instead.

According [to these docs](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9), the request should be in the form of:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "language": "en",
      "id": "1",
      "text": "Hello world. This is some input text that I love."
    },
    {
      "language": "fr",
      "id": "2",
      "text": "Bonjour tout le monde"
    },
    {
      "language": "es",
      "id": "3",
      "text": "La carretera estaba atascada. Había mucho tráfico el día de ayer."
    }
  ]
}
```

How does your request compare?